# How to fetch json data from local folder using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to retrieve json data from a file in a local folder using javascript.

i have the json data like below defined in the folder api/data.json

```
{
    "title": "title",
    "lists": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "title1",
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "item_title_1",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "item_title_2",
                },
             ],
         },
         {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "title2",
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "item_title_2",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "title": "item_title_3",
                },
             ],
         }
     ]
 }
```

i want to fetch this data on application load so i call fetchData method on load in body tag like so

index.html

```
<body onload="fetchData()">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

in the main.js file defined fetchData like so

```
function fetchData() {
    const data = fetch('api/data.json');
    console.log('data', data);
}
```

but this throws error fetchData() is not defined. not sure where the problem is. i am new to javascript and learning it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

**EDIT**

based on answers provided i have tried below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="src/scripts.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="fetchData()">

        <h2>here i am </h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

in the scripts.js file which is in src folder i have defined fetchData method

```
function fetchData() {
    console.log('data');  
}
```

but still gives me fetchData undefined.

Comment: Move the `<script  >` tag inside the `head` part of your HTML, so it loads before `<body>`.

Comment: @trincot: i have tried the same as mentioned but is still  the same.

Comment: Check the console on the network transactions: did the script load?

Answer (score 0):

include main.js before `<body>` tag you're loading the function after its called

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="fetchData()">
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have tried as mentioned and i still get the error. i have edited my question to what i have tried.

Comment: Are you sure the main.js loads?

Comment: Try adding the js file directly to the page, like this :   <html>
<head>
<script>
function fetchData() {
    console.log('data');  
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="fetchData()">
    
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="main.js"> </script>
</head>

<body onload="fetchData()">
</body>
</html>
```

And if the json data doesn't print out on the console. Then , Run your index.html on localhost.

And you don't need to include it in index.html to use javascript.
You can use 'node js' to run js files without using browser. It is much easier in node than linking the script file in html